# How to change the title of a property in a template Word file using PHPWord

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

I am currently using `PHPWord` to create a program that will load, edit, and save a Word file that is a template created by someone else.
In that program, I plan to change the value of Creator in the properties of the template Word file from someone else to my name.

However, I am experiencing the following two problems.

1. If `PHPWord` prioritizes loading the template Word file, the property cannot be set.
2. The contents of the template Word file are discarded when priority is given to property settings.

The following is the current code.

```php
<?php
require_once './PHPWord/vendor/autoload.php';

$template_file = 'sample.docx';
$file_path = "./".$template_file;

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($file_path);

$creater_name = "TARO TANAKA";
$properties = $phpword->getDocumentProperties();
$properties->setCreater($creater_name);

ob_end_clean();
$templateProcessor->save($file_path);
?>
```

I want to be able to both load template Word files and set properties.
(I don't want to touch the updated Word file every time, so I'm asking for a solution using `PHPWord`.)

**Thank you for your response.**